# Cloudant bulk insert errors

Tags: couchdb, cloudant

I'm getting a lot of errors intermittently from Cloudant, when I post several thousand ~1000-character documents 10 at a time to _bulk_docs, from a Node app running on my local machine:

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND samdutton.cloudant.com
```

What does this error mean?

I've found a few similar problems online, but any suggestions how to avoid this error?

Comment: Sam, by randomly do you mean this error is intermittent? I.e. sometimes the bulk request works, sometimes the same request doesn't work. Also, what version of node are you using?

Comment: Hi Chris – yes, I mean intermittent (just edited my question). Node is 0.12.0 – I'll update to 0.12.2.

Comment: Have updated Node to 0.12.2 – still getting intermittent errors: `Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND samdutton.cloudant.com`.

Comment: This problem has been reproduced [here](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/5545#issuecomment-20523190) (not with Cloudant), and a workaround provided [here](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/5545#issuecomment-20568941).  The workaround may be worth a try.

Comment: Did the workaround fix the issue?

Answer (score 2):

"getaddrinfo" represents your machine's inability to use DNS to find an IP address for the domain name "samdutton.cloudant.com". Can you confirm that your machine is able to resolve this DNS record correctly by doing

```
dig samdutton.cloudant.com
```

or

```
nslookup samdutton.cloudant.com
```

from your command line?

Comment: DNS lookup with dig seems OK right now – but, of course, the problem is intermittent. Partial details below.

samdutton.cloudant.com. 30 IN CNAME moonshine.cloudant.com.
moonshine.cloudant.com. 30 IN CNAME lb1.moonshine.cloudant.com.
lb1.moonshine.cloudant.com. 300 IN A 184.173.163.133

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
cloudant.com.  37867 IN NS ns2.p21.dynect.net.
cloudant.com.  37867 IN NS ns4.p21.dynect.net.
cloudant.com.  37867 IN NS ns3.p21.dynect.net.
cloudant.com.  37867 IN NS ns1.p21.dynect.net.